# Java - Add values to two-dimensional Array and how see the array?

Tags: java, android, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array (Arr). I fill points1 and points2 with values.

```
public class Arr {
    float pointX;
    float pointY;
    boolean yesNo;
    String text; 
}

public Arr points1[];
public Arr points2[];   

points1 = new Arr[100];
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) points1[i]= new Arr();    

for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++) {
    points1[j].pointX = getFloat;
    points1[j].pointY = getFloat;
    points1[j].yesNo = getBoolean;
    points1[j].text = getText;
}   

points2 = new Arr[100];
for (int x = 0; x < 100; x++) points2[x]= new Arr();    

for (int y = 0; y < 100; y++) {
    points2[y].pointX = getFloat;
    points2[y].pointY = getFloat;
    points2[y].yesNo = getBoolean;
    points2[y].text = getText;
}
```

This works, but what is, when I have five of them or more (points1, points2, points3...)
How can I make "public Arr points[][]"? And then fill and get the values with e.g. points[0][22].pointX or points[1][10].text?

And how can I see the points[][] array like var_dump in PHP? How list the array?
var_dump example:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  int(1)
  [1]=>
  int(2)
  [2]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "a"
    [1]=>
    string(1) "b"
    [2]=>
    string(1) "c"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a working example

```
package com.stackoverflow.q15134193;

public class Test1 {
    public static Arr[][] points;
    static float getFloat = 1;
    static boolean getBoolean = true;
    static String getText = "hi";

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        points = new Arr[100][];
        for (int i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
            points[i] = new Arr[100];
            for (int j = 0; j < points[i].length; j++)
                points[i][j] = new Arr();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < points[i].length; j++) {
                points[i][j].pointX = getFloat;
                points[i][j].pointY = getFloat;
                points[i][j].yesNo = getBoolean;
                points[i][j].text = getText;
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < points.length; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < points[i].length; j++)
                System.out.println("X: " + points[i][j].pointX + " Y: " 
                        + points[i][j].pointY + " YesNo: " 
                        + points[i][j].yesNo 
                        + " text: "+ points[i][j].text);
    }
}

class Arr {
    public float pointX;
    public float pointY;
    public boolean yesNo;
    public String text;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely clear on what you're trying to achieve, but Java isn't PHP. 
Java has an extensive set of Collections which will give you much better coverage then simple array's.

As I'm not completely sure what you're trying to do, I can't really tell you what collections could do the job, but you could read up on things like Maps and ArrayList.

You could make, per example an ArrayList of 'Arr's like

```
ArrayList<Arr> list = new ArrayList<Arr>();
```

Similarly you can do `ArrayList<Arr, Arr>`, or start working with Maps if you want to store your object Arr together with a key to find it with.

Once you're using a Java Collection, the clearest way to print these is just looping over it  , with something like

```
for(Arr a : list){
  Log.d("my_tag", "My list contains"+a.toString());
}
```

Comment: It's not totally clear to me what OP would like to achieve but, as Stefan says, I would definitely go with one of the various java Maps...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of 2D array, you can use [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html).

```
ArrayList<Arr> points = new ArrayList<Arr>();
```

Now, access an index as following:

```
points.get(22).pointX OR points.get(10).text
```

Try to print the arraylist `points`, to see a near about string output:

```
System.out.println(points);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement a toString() method in your class Arr, and then call

```
Log.i("mytag", Arrays.toString(points1));
```

as explained here [how see an array in logcat for android](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9068689/2119061)