# Adding a value to string array in android

Tags: android, arrays

i am trying [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15134193/java-add-values-to-two-dimensional-array-and-how-see-the-array)

as to add values to single as well as 2dim array dynamically,
but while adding values it shows null pointer ,

here is my code

```
Arr points1[];
    points1 = new Arr[listItemList.size()];

    for(int i=0;i<listItemList.size();i++)
    {

        ListItemReminderSummary listItem = listItemList.get(i);
        Log.i("listItem.Car_Id", listItem.Car_Type);

        points1[i].Car_Id = listItem.Car_Id;
        points1[i].Car_Type =  listItem.Car_Type;

    }
    for(int i=0;i<listItemList.size();i++)
    {

         System.out.println( points1[i].Car_Id +  points1[i].Car_Type);
    }
```

Null pointer at `points1[i].Car_Id = listItem.Car_Id;`

any suggestion, 
thnx in advance.

Comment: How about using `ArrayList` instead of using simply an `Array` ?

Comment: actually m ussing arraylist which i want to convert it into array

Comment: Then may be this link could help you: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5374311/1739882

Answer (score 1):

initialize the items in Array...

```
for (int i = 0; i < listItemList.size(); i++) {
        ListItemReminderSummary listItem = listItemList.get(i);
        Log.i("listItem.Car_Id", listItem.Car_Type);
        points[i] = new Arr();
        points1[i].Car_Id = listItem.Car_Id;
        points1[i].Car_Type = listItem.Car_Type;
}
```

Comment: when i use your second method it give error of 01-02 02:15:35.127: E/AndroidRuntime(960): java.lang.ArrayStoreException: source[0] of type com.example.ListItemReminderSummary cannot be stored in destination array of type com.example.Arr[]

Comment: first, check your ArrayList contains items.

Comment: yes  Log.i("listItem.Car_Id", listItem.Car_Type); it prints the value on log

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialize cells of array.

```
 for(int i=0;i<listItemList.size();i++){
 points[i] = new Arr();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not Allocated memory to the **Arr** that is why you're trying to dereference an uninitialised pointer (i.e. writing to a random chunk of memory), which is undefined behaviour.

Change ur starting 2 lines

```
Arr points1[] = new Arr[listItemList.size()];


for (int i = 0; i < listItemList.size(); i++)
{
    ListItemReminderSummary listItem = listItemList.get(i);
    Log.i("listItem.Car_Id", listItem.Car_Type);
    points1[i].Car_Id = listItem.Car_Id;
    points1[i].Car_Type = listItem.Car_Type;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you make sure that listItemList.get(i) returns a value? Perhaps there is nothing returned from this.